# Node JS pkg executable not able to read files from outside?

Tags: node.js, exe, yarnpkg

I have a JS script which I package into an executable using pkg --public filename.js

I want to read data from a file like this:

```
let filename = __dirname + "/data/streets_profiles.csv" 
fs.createReadStream(filename)
.pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }))
.on('data', (r) => {
    //console.log("r: ", r);
    data.push(r);        
})
.on('end', async () => {
 //... do something
```

While this works well when I just run the script with **node filename.js** in the VS code powershell, when I package the script into a executable I get this
[the error from executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIURZ.png)

I found a solution, which would be to add the csv file path I want to read into **package.json** assets, but I would like to be able to change the data in this csv file without creating another executable, and for it to not be locked in the executable as a asset but rather as a standalone editable file which can be read by the exe, is there any way i could achieve this or any better way to create a executable without these limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a long research I found out that the packaged executable is located in C:/snapshots for me so getting `__dirname` was useless, but `path.dirname(process.execPath)` solved my issue as it can get the actual location of the file and therefore actions with files in the same directory are enabled

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/195#issuecomment-322831063) and got it to work.

Basically, replacing all occurrences of `__dirname` with `process.cwd()` got it to work.

> **NOTE:**
> A simple find-and-replace will not work. You also need to remove any extra relative paths like "../../" from all occurrences. So `path.join(__dirname, '../../', 'uploads')` will become `path.join(process.cwd(), 'uploads')`

Conclusively,

- All paths in your source code must be relative to the project root, and not relative to other files.
- The executable must be run from the project root.
- Static files and `.env` load just fine if placed next to the executable.